# What is the basic implementation principle of CSS？

Tags: css

I haven't found a suitable answer.
Why can html `style="color:red;"` set the font to red?
Hope to get help.

Comment: You are referencing inline CSS. More info can be found here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp and https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_howto_inline

Comment: Thanks very much.This is not the result I want to

Answer (score 0):

**The three principles I use to build and maintain my CSS are consistency, succinctness, and separation (or CSS).**

Refer this for more: [Principles of Good CSS Design](https://cobwwweb.com/three-principles-good-css-design#:%7E:text=The%20three%20principles%20I%20use,framework%20you%20choose%20to%20adopt.)

[Basic CSS principles](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/application_development/9781849697965/1/ch01lvl1sec10/basic-css-principles)